# Is there a specific verb for the "thunder" phenomenon?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

You can see a lightning strike before you hear the thunder. Is there a specific verb for this phenomenon? (e.g. you can see something before you hear it)

Comment: Please give an example sentence with a ______ space.

Comment: It's not clear for me what you mean by a phenomenon. May be you could use the word "supersonic"?

Comment: Light travels faster than sound.

Comment: The answer to your question, as I understand it, is this: *I am **experiencing** the results of the laws of physics.* As @EdwinAshworth suggested, please add an example sentence to illustrate how you would use the word you're seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb to describe that phenomenon is "Delay".

Comment: I think the question was looking for something that was more specific.

Comment: I think the question is asking for a verb for the **experience.** *Delay* is what happens to the sound, not a verb for what the observer experiences (sight before sound).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think that's nit-picking. The observer / listener ***experiences [audio] delay / lag***. We don't normally have dedicated verbs for "to undergo the process of experiencing" specific phenomena like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fine: put that in an answer. What the question is asking for is a verb for "experience delay".

Comment: Nah - I'll content myself with simply upvoting this answer!  (Even though strictly speaking I'd prefer it to say *The **noun** to describe that...* :)

Comment: The question as it stands is too nebulous for ELU, and 'delay' a simplistic response.

Comment: This is exactly the verb I was about to provide as an answer, so +1 for that. I would suggest, however, expanding the answer. Give a dictionary definition of the word (with a citation and link), as well as some example sentences that show its use in this context. (*The thunder was **delayed**.*, etc.) Note that *delay* is also a noun, which can be used equally well here.